# After ejecting from Expo when i try creating a standalone app(apk) display's "Are you sure XDE or EXP is running?"

Tags: react-native, react-redux, expo

Is it necessary to run expo packager .. Even after ejecting from Expo..? How can i create a standalone app without expo packager. I want to create an apk for distribution how should i proceed..?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `exp start` (and leave it running) before opening Android 
Studio and building the app.

As seen here: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/772#issuecomment-397048049